# ASP.NET Impersonation: UnauthorizedAccessException on local file (UNC works)

Tags: asp.net, impersonation, unc

i'm using ASP.NET impersonation with LogonUser (advapi32.dll). Code in short:

```
LogonUser( username, domain, password, 9, 0, out handle );
WindowsIdentity.Impersonate( handle.DangerousGetHandle() );
```

When I enter my user credentials I get an UnauthorizedAccessException (Access to the path 'C:\Folder\test.txt' is denied.) when accessing a **local** file:

```
using( FileStream fileStream = new FileStream( "C:\Folder\test.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite ) )
```

I do have full permission on this file.

It works when accessing a file on a network share (UNC):

```
using( FileStream fileStream = new FileStream( "\\Server\Folder\test.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite ) )
```

Anyone have experience with this behaviour? Thank you.